# Spotify web API issue

Tags: php, spotify, webapi

I tried to connect Spotify to my app with API calls,
but everything goes well but after the authorization, I get an error and I'm stuck.

Here is the error:

> The resource <URL> was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.
> login:1 Failed to launch 'com.lametric.developer.5ff35d10-429d-4454-8547-8b95d4b838a0://?code=AQC6nBxS9LddIe3Rbpd5_Zvkq26T2x5WIE0IWFKV_5e9ktQVMAjaaGgKac48OZwuSxwNt4s2F4pztQtWSdqaGaakzZGo3gbIfh8vLXxDdzbeiBuwoJHRzdM4wsGtMQ5kOQ1QKoX4LWAmVtIDrYN4xk6fMg9seiVOCHh2gO42pvgpJn2X3WK3s4XYXMV1E_5vnrwDWWHCduGlfG3-ADG0eDgC0Lx_Lzl4aSiG1b3dXEgkOQcM8RWfQpzIgKIPoKwK-yk#*=*' because the scheme does not have a registered handler.

Here is my code:

```
// Remplacez ces valeurs par vos propres identifiants Spotify
$clientId = 'xxxxx';
$clientSecret = 'xxxxx';

// URL d'autorisation Spotify
$authorizeUrl = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize';

// URL de redirection après l'autorisation
$redirectUri = "https://developer.lametric.com/redirect";

// URL du token d'accès Spotify
$tokenUrl = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token';

// URL de base de l'API Spotify
$apiBaseUrl = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1';

// Définissez les autorisations nécessaires pour l'API
$scope = 'user-read-currently-playing user-read-playback-state';

// Obtenez le code d'autorisation Spotify
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $code = $_GET['code'];

  // Échangez le code d'autorisation contre un jeton d'accès Spotify
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $tokenUrl);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=' . $code . '&redirect_uri=' . $redirectUri);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($clientId . ':' . $clientSecret)));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $tokenData = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  // Stockez le jeton d'accès dans une session
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = json_decode($tokenData)->access_token;
}


// Vérifiez si l'utilisateur est autorisé
if (!isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {

  // Redirigez l'utilisateur vers la page d'autorisation Spotify
  $authorizeParams = array(
    'client_id' => $clientId,
    'response_type' => 'code',
    'redirect_uri' => 'https://developer.lametric.com/redirect',
    'scope' => $scope,
  );
    $url=http_build_query($authorizeParams);
    $url2=rawurldecode($url);
    header("location:". $authorizeUrl . '?' . $url2);
    //die();

}
```

Please someone could help me to debug this cause my redirect uri is correctly register...

[image]

[image]

after I changed the callback uri

[image]

Comment: That sounds like a client-side error message, apparently your system has created an `<link rel="preload">` element, but the address given appears to be broken? `Failed to launch 'com.lametric.developer.5ff35d10-429d-4454-8547-8b95d4b838a0://?code=` - somehow that `com.lametric.developer.5ff35d10-429d-4454-8547-8b95d4b838a0` part appears to have been inserted in the place where actually the protocol should go in a URL, `http://` or `https://`.

Comment: All a bit unclear how that is supposed to relate to the code you have shown above though, because neither does that string appear in there, nor are you actually creating such a preload link.

Comment: `$url=http_build_query($authorizeParams); $url2=rawurldecode($url);` - `http_build_query` just did a good job properly encoding these parameters - why are you _destroying_ all that effort now, by applying `rawurldecode` on the next line? Definitively wrong.

Comment: @CBroe ok i understand but it's exactely the same with `header("location:". $authorizeUrl . '?' . $url)'

Comment: @CBroe i just change the code to delete the wrong line but i don't undersand why the adress given appears to be broken

Comment: I don't understand _why_ any link prefetch would be involved here in the first place, that makes really rather little sense IMHO. Or where that value `com.lametric.developer.5ff35d10-429d-4454-8547-8b95d4b838a0` would come from in the first place. Are you calling the above code directly, or is that part of any framework?

Comment: @CBroe i put the result here above

Comment: So are you saying that you are getting this error, _while_ you are still on the Spotify login dialog page? And before you even submitted the form? That would not make any sense. And looking at the actual requests, it looks like this is happening only after you already got redirected to your own page. Sorry, but at the moment you are rather adding confusion here than clarification.

Comment: If this is happening _after_ you got redirected back from Spotify to your own system, then I don't see any other explanation than that it must be _your_ system as well, that somehow generates this link element that tries to preload a faulty URL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253345/discussion-between-pierre-marie-and-cbroe).